# Batch dos : Set variable exclamation mark with exclamation mark inside

Tags: batch-file, variable-assignment

I'm sorry if the title is ambiguous.

I would like to set a variable shorting it at the same time.

Something like this :

```
rem FILE_NAME was set before...
SET FILE_NAME=test
rem Same for COUNT
SET COUNT=1
SET FILE_NAME=!FILE_NAME:~-!COUNT!!
```

Theoritically if I do :

```
echo !FILE_NAME!
```

It should give me : tes

There's an error. I understand why, but I really don't know which syntax adopt. And I can't use %

I also tried :

```
SET FILE_NAME=!FILE_NAME:~-^^!COUNT^^!!
```

But it's useless because I want to assign variable not to escape it to show it.

Can you please help me because I'm searching a way since this morning ?

Thank you !

Comment: is all this part of if condition or for loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
rem FILE_NAME was set before...
SET FILE_NAME=test
rem Same for COUNT
SET COUNT=1
for %%# in (!count!) do SET FILE_NAME=!FILE_NAME:~-%%#!
```